# Newlines sometimes don't display correctly in .csv (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science, newline

I'm writing a script that organises data for an Neural Network project, specifically a sentence and it's label I assign it. The part of my script that outputs the data as a `.csv` file (that I had temporarily stored in a list) is so:

```
    with open(out_file, 'w+') as out:
        out.write("sentence, label \n")  # Write a header for .csv file
        for item in corp_list:
            out.write(item + '\n')  # Item is intended to look like: '[sentence], [label]'
```

Like above, each `item` in `corp_list` is intended to be formatted like in this example:

> I like to go to the mountains, L

Where 'L' is the label I assign it.

Most of my data when I load it useing `pd.read_csv` looks perfect, with the newline separating each entry as intended. But, there are about 11,000 entries that look something like this:

> He is my brother, E\nWe can't wait to go to on holidays, N\nMy father was a painter, T\nShe hates the sea, E

It starts 'merging' entries into one big entry which renders my dataset very hard to use. I'm really unsure as to why most newlines work, but some of these for some reason don't. How I format the data and write it to the file never changes for all of my 16 million entries.

Any advice on whether it's thought to be a newline/code issue or perhaps within my own datset.

**Edit:**

My data has no commas, just to note.
This problem does not happen when I write the same list to a normal `.txt` file. It only happens when I write it and then read it as a CSV, either through a Pandas dataframe or through the `CSV` module's reader method.

Also, when I output my list to a `txt` file and then load that back in sentence by sentence into a list vs. a `csv` into a dataframe, the incorrect entries are slightly changed. All incorrect entries are missing the spaces at the comma, for example here is what a correct entry looks like:

> I like to go to the mountains, L

compared to an incorrect entry (of course, like mentioned, with a lot more concatenated onto it):

> I like to go to the mountains,L

And only the last label from any long, incorrect string entry is set as the label.

Comment: You're seeing literal `\n` in the file instead of line breaks?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that these are in the `corp_list` data itself. Your code looks fine.

Comment: What does `count(item for item in corp_list if r'\n' in item)` show?

Comment: are there meant to be spaces in the column header?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I'm seeing the literal characters `\n` instead of the actual line break. Also, is count a method for strings? It seems to be a big thing in Python2, but I'm using 3.7.7. I did `corp_list.count(...)` and got `0`.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `len([item for item in corp_list if r'\n' in item])`

Comment: The point is to search `corp_list` for elements that have literal `\n` in them.

Comment: And you can get their indexes with `[i for i, item in enumerate(corp_list) if r'\n' in item]`

Comment: @Barmar It's also 0. It seems to be an issue with outputting it to a `.csv` file/pd dataframe then, since 0 literal `\n` characters is a good thing I presume. Also, forgot originally to say thanks for offering your help.

Comment: There's no CSV code here. You're just writing ordinary strings to a text file. There's no reason why it should start writing literal `\n` spontaneously.

Comment: If you have a pandas dataframe, why aren't you using `pd.to_csv()`?

Comment: @Barmar Well my ouput are ordinary strings that I write to a file ending in `.csv` which means programs automatically open it as a CSV and display it as such. I then load my CSV as a pandas datafram using `pd.read_csv`, kind of like the opposite of what you were saying.

Comment: I still think it must be a problem in the original data. Can you find any difference in the records that get written incorrectly? Can you extract a few of them into a small test case and see if the problem still exists?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, separating the two strings

```
with open(out_file, 'w+') as out:
    out.write("sentence, label \n")  # Write a header for .csv file
    for item in corp_list:
        out.write(item)
        out.write('\n') # Item is intended to look like: '[sentence], [label]'
```

or try using f-strings

```
with open('out_file', 'w+') as out:
    out.write("sentence, label \n")  # Write a header for .csv file
    for item in corp_list:
        out.write(f'{item}\n') # Item is intended to look like: '[sentence], [label]'
```

It is not recommended to use '+' sign string concatenation for high complexity. Maybe there are some implicit string concatenations hidden in your data, being responsible for the merges. If this doesn't help, the problem pretty likely originates from your data.

Comment: I just added information in my original post about this occurring only when read as a CSV. Would you have any knowledge if implicit string concatenation is a lot more sensitive in this format (as in, more ways to do it accidentally)?